# Alternate Locust Crusades

Tags: exalted, exalted-1e

I have an old copy of **Time of Tumult** that has the original writeup of the Locust Crusade.  That chapter, of course, is crammed full of stuff, because it provides writeups for Alchemicals, talks about Autochthonia, and describes the Locust Crusade itself.

I dimly recall another book -- possibly a first edition book -- that provided alternative Locust Crusades.  The chronicle that I'm running right now is set primarily in the North and I am considering introducing the Locust Crusade as a plotline in the North.  However, I am exceedingly lazy, and if someone else has already done the legwork for me on this, I am inclined to steal it.

From reviewing the previews of the PDFs of the 2nd edition **Alchemicals** and **Autochthonia** books, it looks like the info I'm looking for isn't in there.  But I'm not positive.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book you are thinking of is almost certainly: [Exalted: The Autochthonians](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=368).  This was the 1st Ed equivalent to the Manual of Exalted power which also included setting information on Autochthonia and Alchemical Exalted.  It also provided 3 separate scenarios on how the Locust Crusade could play out.  It's been awhile since I've read them but if I recall correctly one roughly follows the Locust Crusade as laid out by Time of Tumult, one involves the players running around Creation to try and reactivate some manses to awaken Autochthon and the last involves the invasion of Autochthon by the Deathlord First and Forsaken Lion.

As towards having the Locust Crusade affect the south in none of the scenarios got too far in that direction.  The default crusade still rampages all over the south and the one in Autochthonia naturally takes place in there.  The only one that might touch upon in it is the remaining scenario since that involves traipsing all over Creation.

Comment: Thanks -- that must be what I am thinking of.  I guess I'll have to be creative on my own if I want the invasion to happen in the North.  Or leave it going on in the South until my players' characters reach the point that they're aware of the South in any real terms.

Comment: I think it should also be mentioned that many of the fans didn't have a particularly good view of the locust crusade as detailed in said book, so don't feel to obligated to uphold it's views on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

**The Locust Crusade doesn't happen in 2e by Default**

You can read a summary of the relevant forum posts from the designers on this blog: http://nobilis.me/quotes:not-the-locust-crusade

It's also discussed here a bit:
http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?573339-Exalted-What-Part-Sucked-The-Most-About-The-Locust-War-(from-1E)/page8

So really, if you want it to happen I think you're stuck with 1e material, at least for now. (Though given their stance on default settings, it'd probably be in the form of a long "What if..." section).

I *think* there was some mention of "What would happen if the Alchemicals showed up..." in [Return of the Scarlet Empress](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588463915), but I'll have to check my book when I get home to be sure.

Comment: There is discussion of it in Return of the Scarlet Empress, for sure.  Thanks for the links, I will check into it.